# evaluate(cell) vs evaluateInCell(cell) difference in poi library?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am working on poi library. I want to evaluate some formula cell which is more than 255 columns.

```
    XSSFRow row219 = sheet.createRow(219);
    XSSFCell vv0 = (XSSFCell) row219.createCell(255);
    vv0.setCellValue(40);

    XSSFCell vv = (XSSFCell) row219.createCell(256);
    vv.setCellValue(70);
    XSSFCell cell = sheet.createRow(1).createCell(1);
    cell.setCellFormula("OFFSET(IV220,0,1)");
    XSSFFormulaEvaluator evaluator =
            (XSSFFormulaEvaluator) workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
    evaluator.evaluateInCell(cell);
```

but it gives result **#REF!** in cell. but if I use below code I am getting my expected result

```
    XSSFRow row219 = sheet.createRow(219);
    XSSFCell vv0 = (XSSFCell) row219.createCell(255);
    vv0.setCellValue(40);

    XSSFCell vv = (XSSFCell) row219.createCell(256);
    vv.setCellValue(70);

    XSSFCell cell = sheet.createRow(1).createCell(1);
    cell.setCellFormula("OFFSET(IV220,0,1)");
    XSSFFormulaEvaluator evaluator =
            (XSSFFormulaEvaluator) workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

    evaluator.evaluate(cell);
```

Then I am getting my expected value 70.

I want to know the difference between **evaluator.evaluateInCell(cell);** and **evaluator.evaluate(cell);** though it is using same abstract class inside poi library

```
 protected abstract CellValue evaluateFormulaCellValue(Cell var1);
```

and same implementation of this abstract class `BaseXSSFFormulaEvaluator` but why result is differ ?

**NB: I am using poi library 3.17**

Comment: Where are you getting the expected value? The difference between `evaluateInCell` and `evaluate` is that `evaluateInCell` **replaces** the formula with the evaluated value. As it is documented, it: "puts the formula result back into the cell, in place of the old formula." The `FormlaEvaluator` definitelly is wrong when evaluating `OFFSET` for `XSSF`. But if you are opening the sheet in Excel then, after `evaluateInCell` the wrong evaluated value is in the cell but after `evaluate` the formula remains in the cell and will be reevaluated from Excel's GUI. So Excel evaluates correct then.

Comment: I know that "evaluateInCell and evaluate is that evaluateInCell replaces the formula with the evaluated value. As it is documented, it: "puts the formula result back into the cell, in place of the old formula." But I am wondered when evaluateInCell  call and coulumn number more than 255 Its not return value. Its Returns #REF! but if column number <255 it gives correct result

Comment: The `apache poi` `FormlaEvaluator` definitely is wrong when evaluating OFFSET for XSSF since it uses the old limits of Excel 2003 for column count and row count. But both `evaluateInCell` **as well as** `evaluate` evaluate wrong.